# Is it all right to have multiple app delegates in the same project, for different targets?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm involved in developing an iOS app. The first thing that struck me was the multiple app delegates in the top level project, which has multiple target outputs. I do know that the sub-projects each have their own app delegate. I was told by my team members that those app delegates are used for different targets, but they have almost the same code, except that some  variables are derived from a different class or sub-project. What are the pros and cons in having multiple app delegates in a project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This structure is fine, *if there is stuff in the app delegate that is actually different*. If some of it is the same, consider how that code could be restructured (so you don't have duplicate code). Putting the common code in a superclass is one approach, but there are several others. Because subclassing is so strong, another approach is often preferable (e.g. composition).

One gotcha of the app delegate is that it can affect your resources -- i.e. if the class names differ, then you may be faced with minor differences in resources (e.g. NIBs) when these resources could just be identical.

**Basic Rule of Thumb:** If you find yourself facing duplicate code, find a way to avoid duplicating that code, or a way to remove that duplicate code in the event it's already been duplicated.

Comment: yes there are lots of duplicate code. i'm just reviewing the code. i havent done any subclassing or superclassing for appdelegate. so it would be better to have base class of type UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> like normal appdelegate and then subclass the appdelegates from the base class and where important orverride the methods or use additional variables. that's what just come to my mind right away. any other suggestion is also welcomed.

Comment: @user i'd just start by moving everything (reasonably) possible out of the app delegate :) consider composition over subclassing, and you can figure out dynamically what app you are running by querying the app's plist. so this duplicate code is unnecessary. if you're in a leadership position, just tell them to stop duplicating code and figure out how to restructure the program/targets. all these special cases and duplicate code usually become maintenance nightmares (in my experience).

Comment: composition sounds interesting. i have no idea how its done right now but have to learn that. thank you for taking time to explain.

Comment: believe me you dont wannna see the app delegate that i'm seeing right now. it has over 2000 lines of code in it forget about the duplicate :-) its already a nightmare.

Comment: @user well, one example of composition (if you even wanted to keep all that in the app delegate) would be to have an ivar of the app delegate whose type/class varies, depending on the app that is running. so when you init the app delegate, then the app delegate can figure out which app it is, and then create a `MONApp1DataProvider` or `MONApp2DataProvider`, depending on the app that is being run. Of course, these would either adopt the same protocol or have a common superclass for their customized behavior.

Comment: by the way, can you please recommend any link/book/tutorial for composition.

Comment: @user *believe me you dont wannna see the app delegate that i'm seeing right now. it has over 2000 lines of code…* -- i believe you! =)

Comment: @user recommendation: this may be a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance